# IDENTITY not generating sequential values

Tags: azure-synapse

I am running the below query to create a dimension table; however the identity column is not yielding sequential values; the values are very random. Any reason for this?

I have tried a stored procedure and also a manual insert; but the result is the same

```
CREATE TABLE Dim.CDIM_State 
(   
    intStateDimKey int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    txtState nvarchar(250),
    dtCreatedOn datetime,
    dtModifiedOn datetime
)
WITH
(
DISTRIBUTION = REPLICATE,
CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
)
```

The output is something like this; I expect sequential values viz. 1,2,3,4,5

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is correct. There are separate counters for each distribution.

It won't affect your dimension, the values will always be unique.