# Azure SQL DW - Identity column values

Tags: identity-column, azure-synapse

I'm inserting primary/composite keys into an intermediary database table with an `identity(1,1) bigint` column. In more traditional relationship databases, this column increments by 1 for each new key in the table, creating a surrogate key for the values. However, in Azure SQL DW, the values are non-contiguous, as noted in the documentation:

> The IDENTITY property doesn't guarantee the order in which the surrogate values are allocated, which reflects the behavior of SQL Server and Azure SQL Database. However, in Azure SQL Data Warehouse, the absence of a guarantee is more pronounced.

Thus, the `id` column of my table for only 4 unique values will look like this:

`id, 1, 6, 8, 20`
as opposed to
`id, 1, 2, 3, 4`

I know I can work around this by using the `row_number()` function and a `max` of the surrogate `id` column from the table to create the surrogate key myself. However, I'm concerned that this isn't the intention of Azure SQL DW and will hinder database performance.

`declare @current_val as bigint = (select coalesce(max(id), 0) from dbo.reseeding_table);`

Thus, I'm concerned the values of the id `identity` column will jump past its limit because of the way it is implemented by Azure. Should I trust the functionality of Azure SQL DW's `identity` column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IDENTITY not generating sequential values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56258623/identity-not-generating-sequential-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by Greg Galloway, the question is very similar to a recent topic on sequential values.

Because you raised a couple of specific concerns, I think it is different enough to require its own answer.

1. Using row_number() will not hinder performance. I used it all the time in preference to IDENTITY.
2. You can definitely trust the identity functions. You might have noticed that the numbers increment by the number of nodes in your configuration, it isn't random. You will always get a new number.

Something to note is that you shouldn't be inserting one row at a time, which you might be doing if you're worried about sequential IDs. You'll find that single inserts are very slow, and could cause concurrency issues if performed by many processes. Think about micro-batching your data, and using Polybase to load it for best performance.